# How to Connect a Database in asp.net using odbc?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I  have a system DSN.How to connect to the database in asp.net using DSN.I wanted the Connection String

Comment: Did you try http://www.connectionstrings.com/ ?

Comment: Ya but i am not getting the exact one

Comment: use connectionstring to obtain the connectionstring and put them in web.config. intialize them in code and open the connection. were are you got problem. ASP.NET website have many video on them. you can watch any for learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the link , has both DSN and DSN less ODBC connectivity using ADO.Net
http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/csharp/ado-net-odbc.html

Answer (score 0):

One way of finding out the connection string is to create a connection in Server Explorer in Visual Studio, then check the properties of the connection and you will see a **Connection String** property that will give you what you need.

Comment: but when i use that it says dsn is not a keyword.whats wrong with it?

Comment: Is this when you try to connect via code? Could you post it on here in that case?

Comment: string consql = "Dsn=databse;uid=sa;pwd=wtl@123!;"                      The error which i get is below                                   Keyword not supported: 'dsn'

Comment: Can you post the rest of it? Particularly the connection class you are using.